# Generate a repeating sequence based on vector

Tags: r, repeat

I am trying to take an existing vector and repeat each element of it six times.  I feel like this should be easy using `rep()` but I keep hitting the wall.
Basically I would like to take this vector:

```
1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
```

And turn it into this:

```
1027 1027 1027 1027 1027 1027 1028 1028 1028 1028 1028 1028 ...
```

Comment: This question is easily solved by using the help function. type ?rep at the command line for this one. No bad intended, learning to use the help in R is really going to save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use **each** argument:

```
rep(c(1027, 1028, 1030, 1032, 1037), each = 6)
#  [1] 1027 1027 1027 1027 1027 1027
#  [7] 1028 1028 1028 1028 1028 1028
# [13] 1030 1030 1030 1030 1030 1030
# [19] 1032 1032 1032 1032 1032 1032
# [25] 1037 1037 1037 1037 1037 1037
```

**times** argument:

```
rep(c(1027, 1028, 1030, 1032, 1037), times = 6)
#  [1] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
#  [6] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
# [11] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
# [16] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
# [21] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
# [26] 1027 1028 1030 1032 1037
```